# How PCA computes the transformed version in `sklearn`?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I'm confused with `sklearn`'s `PCA`([here is the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform)), and its relation with Singular Value Decomposition (SVD).

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Further_components) we have,

> The full principal components decomposition of X can, therefore, be given as **T=WX**,
>   where **W** is a p-by-p matrix of weights whose columns are the eigenvectors of $X^T X$. The transpose of W is sometimes called the whitening or sphering transformation.

Later once it explains the relationship with SVD, we have:

> **X=U $\Sigma W^T$**

So I assume that matrix **W**, embeds samples into latent space (which makes sense noting the dimension of the matrices) and using `transform` module of the class `PCA` in `sklearn` should give the same result as if I was multiplying observation matrix by **W**. However, I checked them and they don't match.

Is there anything wrong that I'm missing or there's a bug in the code?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

x = np.random.rand(200).reshape(20,10)
x = x-x.mean(axis=0)
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(x, full_matrices=False)
pca = PCA().fit(x)

# transformed version based on WIKI: t = X@vh.T = u@np.diag(s)
t_svd1= x@vh.T
t_svd2= u@np.diag(s)
# the pca transform
t_pca = pca.transform(x)

print(np.abs(t_svd1-t_pca).max()) # should be a small value, but it's not :(
print(np.abs(t_svd2-t_pca).max()) # should be a small value, but it's not :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the theoretical Wikipedia description and the practical `sklearn` implementation, but it is not a bug, merely just a stability and reproducibility enhancement.

You have almost pretty much nailed the exact implementation of the PCA, however in order to be able to fully reproduce the computation, `sklearn` developers added one more enforcement to their implementation. The problem stems from the indeterministic nature of SVD, i.e. the SVD does not have a unique solution. That can be easily seen from your equation as well by setting `U_s = -U` and `W_s = -W`, then `U_s` and `W_s` also satisfy:

> X=U_s $\Sigma W_s^T$

More importantly this holds also when switching the signs of columns of `U` and `W`. If we just reverse the signs of k-th column of `U` and `W`, the equality will still hold. You can read more about this issue f.e. here https://prod-ng.sandia.gov/techlib-noauth/access-control.cgi/2007/076422.pdf.

The implementation of PCA deals with this problem by enforcing the highest loading values in absolute values to be always positive, specifically the method `sklearn.utils.extmath.svd_flip` is being used. This way, no matter which sign the resulting vectors have from the indeterministic method `np.linalg.svd`, the loading values in absolutes will remain the same, i.e. the signs of the matrices will remain the same.

Thus in order for your code to have the same result as the `PCA` implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

np.random.seed(41)
x = np.random.rand(200).reshape(20,10)
x = x-x.mean(axis=0)
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(x, full_matrices=False)
max_abs_cols = np.argmax(np.abs(u), axis=0)
signs = np.sign(u[max_abs_cols, range(u.shape[1])])
u *= signs
vh *= signs.reshape(-1,1)
pca = PCA().fit(x)

# transformed version based on WIKI: t = X@vh.T = u@np.diag(s)
t_svd1= x@vh.T
t_svd2= u@np.diag(s)
# the pca transform
t_pca = pca.transform(x)

print(np.abs(t_svd1-t_pca).max()) # pretty small value :)
print(np.abs(t_svd2-t_pca).max()) # pretty small value :)
```

Comment: I asked this question >3 yrs ago, and since then found myself revisiting your answer multiple times while learning some forgotten nuance each time. Just wanted to say thank you. This answer has helped me a lot.